# Use HTML tags in 'Appearance -> Customise' interface

Tags: html, theme-customizer

When going to 'Customise' within WordPress and the left sidebar pops up, I am unable to use styling tags in the boxes that come up.

Example: the theme I am using has 'Content title' and 'Content text' for different boxes that appear on the page.

Typing HTML tags actually shows the tags on the page and doesn't apply the code to the text. It is worth noting this is not specific to this theme; it applies everywhere throughout the 'Customise' sidebar. Is there a way to make HTML work in this?

Comment: It absolutely is dependent on the theme. When adding a control to the customiser the theme author has control over how the field is sanitised and escaped. So if the theme author wants to support HTML they can do that. WordPress itself doesn’t have many of its own controls, but if they are being output in the theme’s templates then the theme is controlling whether or not HTML is allowed So you’ll need to ask your theme’s author for assistance with this.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thanks for the reply. So in theory, as I have all of the theme files, would I myself be able to make these changes myself so that HTML is supported?

Answer (score 1):

> Thanks for the reply. So in theory, as I have all of the theme files,
> would I myself be able to make these changes myself so that HTML is
> supported?

It's generally a bad idea to edit the files of a theme or plugin that you did not develop or that you do not control updates for. Any changes will erased on any update and disabling updates or forking the theme or plugin leaves you unable to receive potential bug and security fixes for a codebase that you're less familiar with and less able to fix yourself.

If you still intend to make the change then you need to check two places:

1. The `sanitize_callback` setting provided to a call to `$wp_customize->add_setting()`. Whichever function is being passed here is responsible for sanitizing the data before it's saved. Note that the variable name `$wp_customize` could be different in your theme.
2. Wherever the value of the customizer field is being output. This could be a template file, widget or almost anything else. You would be looking for a call to `get_theme_mod()` for that field. If the value is being output through something like `esc_html()` then it's being escaped. Since you mentioned that you can see the HTML tags this is most likely what's happening. You would need to change or remove this function to allow HTML. Since escaping is important I would review [the documentation on escaping](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-sanitization-escaping/) for alternative functions that suit your needs so that you don't leave the value completely unescaped.

Anything more would require specific knowledge of your theme so I suggest reaching out to them if this doesn't help.

Comment: I have searched the theme and found this in customizer.php: "'label' => esc_html__( 'Content ',  'my-theme-name' )". I have spent some time trying to work out how I would implement wp_kses but cannot wrap my head around it. I tried to remove the 'esc_html__' and the brackets but was still unable to add HTML via Customizer (it displays on the webpage as tags). Is there a straightforward way to allow HTML in this field by altering that line of code? Many thanks for your reply